# Routing to contents of model failing due to no ID match

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, url, url-rewriting

I am relatively new to Rails and have recently managed to break the links to the contents of one of my models...

Having previously posted a question here on stackoverflow, I adjusted the `to_param` function in my model, such that the product name would be appended to the product ID.

The changes I made were:

In `products.rb`,

```
def to_param
  "#{id}-#{product_name.parameterize}"  
end
```

In `routes.rb`,

`match '/:id' => 'uniquewetsuits#show'`

This successfully creates the address I am hoping for `/products/ID-product-name`, however, I get an error stating there is no product with `ID=ID-product-name`.

If I navigate to `/products/ID`, I can successfully view the page as normal.

Can anybody inform me as to how I go about reconnecting things so that I do get a match for the longer ID string?

Thanks for your time

EDIT

The contents of the controller are:

```
 def index

#@search = Uniquewetsuit.search(params[:q])
#@findwetsuits = @search.result(:distinct => true)

#if @findwetsuits.count > 0
 # @uniquewetsuits = @findwetsuits.all
#else
  @uniquewetsuits = Uniquewetsuit.all
#end

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # index.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @uniquewetsuits }
end
end

# GET /uniquewetsuits/1
# GET /uniquewetsuits/1.xml
def show
@uniquewetsuit = Uniquewetsuit.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # show.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @uniquewetsuit }
end
end

# GET /uniquewetsuits/new
# GET /uniquewetsuits/new.xml
def new
@uniquewetsuit = Uniquewetsuit.new

respond_to do |format|
  format.html # new.html.erb
  format.xml  { render :xml => @uniquewetsuit }
end
end

# GET /uniquewetsuits/1/edit
def edit
@uniquewetsuit = Uniquewetsuit.find(params[:id])
end

# POST /uniquewetsuits
# POST /uniquewetsuits.xml
def create
@uniquewetsuit = Uniquewetsuit.new(params[:uniquewetsuit])

respond_to do |format|
  if @uniquewetsuit.save
    format.html { redirect_to(@uniquewetsuit, :notice => 'Uniquewetsuit was successfully created.') }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @uniquewetsuit, :status => :created, :location => @uniquewetsuit }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "new" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @uniquewetsuit.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# PUT /uniquewetsuits/1
# PUT /uniquewetsuits/1.xml
def update
@uniquewetsuit = Uniquewetsuit.find(params[:id])

respond_to do |format|
  if @uniquewetsuit.update_attributes(params[:uniquewetsuit])
    format.html { redirect_to(@uniquewetsuit, :notice => 'Uniquewetsuit was successfully updated.') }
    format.xml  { head :ok }
  else
    format.html { render :action => "edit" }
    format.xml  { render :xml => @uniquewetsuit.errors, :status => :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
end

# DELETE /uniquewetsuits/1
# DELETE /uniquewetsuits/1.xml
def destroy
@uniquewetsuit = Uniquewetsuit.find(params[:id])
@uniquewetsuit.destroy

respond_to do |format|
  format.html { redirect_to(uniquewetsuits_url) }
  format.xml  { head :ok }
end
end
```

Comment: In your actual Product.find method in the controller where youo actually find the method . You will need to break the params[:id] to pull out ID from the params params[:id].spilt('-')[0].to_i and pass the resulting id to the methods. I would like to know the reason of why you are replacing the ID with '9-product' format.

Comment: Actually that's not required. A string that is prefixed with a number will turn into that number when calling `to_i` on it. So `"99-foo".to_i == 99`

Comment: Can you add the contents of your Uniquewetsuits controller. The `/prodocts/:id` route works because your routing to the right controller. Are you calling `Product.find(params[:id])` in `UniquewetsuitsController#show` ?

Comment: I have updated the original question to include this information.  I have the same problem with both the edit and show commands currently.  The general principle works as it worked perfectly until very recently and now cannot find what i have changed...

Comment: Can you replace your route to match '/products/:product/:id' => 'uniquewetsuits#show' so that youo can pass the product name separately? something  like "products/product_name/1" and by doing this you will also not have to update tour to_param method in the backend.

Comment: This idea does work to some extent (i.e. it can find the product correctly :)), however if i use ` match 'uniquewetsuits/:product_name/:id' => 'uniquewetsuits#show'`, it just generates the URL uniquewetsuits/ID.  Why does the product_name not appear in the URL (it is a parameter of uniquewetsuits)?

Comment: It appears that using this method doesn't enable me to add any additional specification between 'uniquewetsuits' and 'ID'?